# JSF2 PrimeFaces Installaion

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use PrimeFaces. I followed all the instructions on the [webpage](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html)

**My POM:**

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>2.0.0</version>  
</dependency> 

[...]

<repository>  
    <id>prime-repo</id>  
    <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>  
    <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>  
    <layout>default</layout>  
</repository>
```

Just works I guess! At least the `primefaces-2.0.0.jar` has been downloaded!

**Next my web.xml:**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>  
           org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet  
       </servlet-class>  
   </servlet>  

   <servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>  
   </servlet-mapping>
```

I use tomcat 6 and so far I know it doesn't support servlet 3.0 that's why I have to add a servlet.

**Next my xhtml codes:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" >
    [...]
    <p:editor value="#{projectData.description}" width="640px" height="320px"></p:editor>
```

So far, it's not being rendered. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Before doing anything else, upgrade to the latest release (2.1)! 2.0.0 is _really_ old...

Comment: Oh thank you for that information, couldn't find a version log on the website

Comment: @Sven, its been long time since you have posted this question, but currently I am at your stage. My simple primefaces application is not getting displayed properly in browser. How did you solved your problem? If possible have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219372/simple-primefaces-application-not-working

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you don't request the page through the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. If it is mapped on for example`*.jsf`, then you need to ensure that your request URL matches it. I.e. open the page by http://example.com/context/page.jsf and thus not by http://examlpe.com/context/page.xhtml.

If that doesn't help, then the firstnext step is to read the server logs for any errors or warnings. Also, checking the generated HTML output (rightclick browser, *View Source*) if the `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` are been parsed into `<head>` and `<body>` may give hints about if the `FacesServlet` is doing its job well or not.

Comment: I am not sure I have got what you meant. I posted my FacesServlet declaration, so you can take a look. I request the page through the url-pattern (I think)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a simple servlet container, and doesn't contain JSF2 jars. Primefaces is just a component suite **on top** of the base JSF2 installation (could be [Sun's RI: Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/), or [Myfaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/index.html)). First you have to download and configure either of those, and then Primefaces will work.

Answer (score 0):

I read the installation page and it seems that you need this to occur somewhere inside the `<html>` tag:

```
     <head>  
         <p:resources />  
     <head>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am using JSF2 and the installation page says: 'If you're using PrimeFaces 2.x with JSF you can skip this section as native JSF2 apis are used in this case.' But anyways I tried it and it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an `<h:head>` element in your page and not just `<head>` since this is required by `primefaces`