# Simple primefaces application not working

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, tomcat6, primefaces

I am trying to build simple JSF application using primefaces but somehow primefaces components are not getting rendered properly. I dont understand what is going wrong.

I am trying to display following Facelet file :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <link type="text/css" 
                rel="stylesheet"
                href="/Themes/primefaces-dot-luv/theme.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:spinner value="100" style="height: 10px" />
        <br/>
        <p:button value="Navigate"></p:button>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I am using eclipse to run the app on tomcat server. When I run the application and view the page source in browser(firefox) I get following source :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Themes/primefaces-dot-luv/theme.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p:spinner value="100" style="height: 10px"></p:spinner>
        <br />
        <p:button value="Navigate"></p:button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think PrimeFaces components are not getting rendered properly. Other JSF tags like `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` are converted correctly to `<head>` and `<body>` elements respectively. Only tags starting with `<p:>` are not converted.

Following is my project structure :

[image]

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>HelloJSF</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using eclipse , tomcat server. JSF 2 and primefaces 3 library.

> Hi, After some close inspection of entire project I found out that
>   primefaces jar dowlonaded from site did not had any classes. Jar
>   itself was corrupt. I downloaded same jar thrice then also jar was
>   getting corrupt. So I downloaded zip file containing source and
>   binaries and my application started working.

Comment: Primefaces relies on some automatic registration facilities from the latest Java EE standards that are not implemented by tomcat6. Don't know if it is possible to manually register them. Recent glassfish versions support it however.

Comment: oh. ok. then will it work in JBoss?

Comment: can you post the contents of the web.xml?  Make sure you have the filters for JSF enabled.

Comment: @aseychell, added web.xml contents

Comment: @Eelke what facilities are you talking about exactly? PF work perfectly well on Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your web.xml servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The way to tell if the Facelets Servlet is processing your xhtml is to look at what the browser receives.   If it looks like your xhtml file then you have something mis-configured.

Comment: The JSF core, HTML and Facelets taglibs are however properly parsed, so `FacesServlet` is definitely been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Your need change

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

to

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Comment: This was introduced since 3.0 M4, but OP is using 3.0 M2. So this answer is wrong. Note that the currently accepted answer of AlanObject is also wrong; the OP already solved the problem by itself (see the quote at the bottom of the question), but the OP never posted it as an answer for some reason (which is indeed confusing and not the right way to use Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your namespace into  **xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"**

and implement button like this way

```
 <p:commandButton value="Home" process="@this" action="actionMethod()" immediate="true" rendered="true or renderingMethod()" />
```