# PrimeFaces components are not displaying when adding PrimeFaces library as "external JAR" to Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I tried setting up the PrimeFaces library. So i added the primefaces-3.4.1.jar using the 'add external jar' command. Than I added the namespace: *xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui* to the html tag. According to the [official documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf) that is all there is to it, for setting it up.

I tried adding a `<p:editor/>` componenet to my page, but it is not displayed.

My project configuration is: Eclipse, JSF 2.1 on Glassfish 3.1

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you did the "add external jar" command wrong. It's not clear from the question how exactly you performed this step, but this should be just a matter of dropping the JAR file in its entirety in the project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder the usual way (as you would do for every 3rd party JAR file the webapp depends on). The way you put the question indicates that you weren't aware about this after all.

Really nothing more needs to be done. If you have fiddled around in project's *Build Path* properties, then you should undo that all to avoid possible collisions in the future. Eclipse is smart enough to set the necessary things automatically right whenever you drop a JAR in projects's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

#### See also:

- [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/how-to-add-jar-libraries-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnotfoundex)

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is the same problem & solution: [Simple primefaces application not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219372/simple-primefaces-application-not-working)

missing servlet-mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem when PrimeFaces JAR is in the wrong place. This only solves another problem which is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3112946

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces jar (primefaces-7.0.jar in my case) has to be available in the folder /WEB-INF/lib at runtime.

Comment: Like mentioned in the 8 year old 4 times upvoted answer ;-)