# Primefaces tags are not working

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to jumpstart my Primefaces 3.2 development using Eclipse 3.6 and Glassfish 3.1 as app server.

When I try to publish my application from Eclipse using this very simple code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:panel header="Login Form">
            <h:form>
                <p:button value="With Icon!" icon="bookmark" />
                <br />
                <p:spinner />
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

The Primefaces is not rendering. The button is showing but no icon and the spinner is showing just an input text.

Not sure but I have put the primefaces jar file at the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Although I see this error at glassfish log.

```
[#|2012-04-17T11:37:56.864+0800|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.), detail=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.)]|#]
```

**Update:**

Sorry here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
  <title><ui:insert name="title">My Test Application</ui:insert></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <ui:insert name="content">

  </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <ui:insert name="footer">
        <br/><br/>Footer!
  </ui:insert>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message says that you're missing the `<h:head></h:head>` tag in your view. Try adding it. Did you target some resources to `<h:head></h:head>`?

Comment: What's in `web.xml`? You need to have a `FacesServlet` configured, like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3599015/139010).

Comment: The problem is what Lion mentioned.  In your template give the `<h:head>`. This will enable the primefaces javascript to be rendered.

Comment: Hi, I have added the needed file.  Do you have any idea please? Thanks

Comment: Add the jsf `<h:head>` in your template instead of the html `<head>` ie., replace the html head tag with the jsf tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make the following change in template.xhtml file, for example

```
<f:view>
  <h:head>
   <title><ui:insert name="title">insert title</ui:insert></title>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-type" />
   <link type = "text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="/your/theme/skin.css" />
   </h:head>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.  It was'nt mentioned in the tutorial regarding this. Eclipse auto generated this file for me.  Anyhow, thanks to everyone for the response.

Comment: @MarkEstrada, I have not used eclipse to autogenerate it.If that is the case it is a bug then.:)